# Django dont watch my app and TemplateDoesNotExist at /news

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls, django-apps

I think its this problem - django watching on mainApp but not on news app - django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Name_User\Desktop\mysite\mainApp\templates\news\posts.html

but i dont know how repair it, iam very new in django

[Directory of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf9kP.png)

ERROR

```html
TemplateDoesNotExist at /news
news/posts.html, news/articles_list.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/news
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
news/posts.html, news/articles_list.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template, line 47
Python Executable: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path: 
['C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\Desktop\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\south-1.0.2-py3.7.egg']
Server time: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 12:20:58 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\Desktop\mysite\mainApp\templates\news\posts.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\news\posts.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\news\posts.html (Source does not exist)
Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\Desktop\mysite\mainApp\templates\news\articles_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\news\articles_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\news\articles_list.html (Source does not exist)
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = response.render() …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py in render
            self.content = self.rendered_content …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py in rendered_content
        template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py in resolve_template
            return select_template(template, using=self.using) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\Victor.INC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in select_template
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain) …
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
AnonymousUser

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable Value
csrftoken 
'LcLM03J6xPa80BrwSvUncgrrF8hBl7CnRlKOtYCxIf5HMTeYoNZVIBPHvcPcBbsr'
META
Variable Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData'
APPDATA 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Roaming'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432 
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME 
'DESKTOP-GKBKG6I'
COMSPEC 
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONTENT_LENGTH 
''
CONTENT_TYPE 
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'LcLM03J6xPa80BrwSvUncgrrF8hBl7CnRlKOtYCxIf5HMTeYoNZVIBPHvcPcBbsr'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE 
'mysite.settings'
DRIVERDATA 
'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData'
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING 
'Internet Explorer'
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING 
'Default'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE 
'CGI/1.1'
HOMEDRIVE 
'C:'
HOMEPATH 
'\\Users\\Victor.INC'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING 
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE 
'en-US,en;q=0.9'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL 
'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'csrftoken=LcLM03J6xPa80BrwSvUncgrrF8hBl7CnRlKOtYCxIf5HMTeYoNZVIBPHvcPcBbsr'
HTTP_HOST 
'127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_REFERER 
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST 
'document'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE 
'navigate'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE 
'same-origin'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER 
'?1'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS 
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36')
JDK 
'C:\\Games\\JAVA\\jdk1.8.0_141\\bin'
KOMPAS_SDK 
'D:\\kompas\\SDK\\'
LOCALAPPDATA 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER 
'\\\\DESKTOP-GKBKG6I'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS 
'4'
ONEDRIVE 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\OneDrive'
OS 
'Windows_NT'
PATH 
('C:\\Program Files\\RailsInstaller\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\RailsInstaller\\Ruby2.2.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common '
 'Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Games\\iverilog\\gtkwave\\bin;C:\\Games\\iverilog\\bin;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\NVIDIA '
 'Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA '
 'NvDLISR;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\wget;C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\;C:\\Games\\JAVA\\jdk1.8.0_141\\bin;C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Games\\Microsoft '
 'VS '
 'Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;')
PATHEXT 
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL'
PATH_INFO 
'/news'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE 
'x86'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 
'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER 
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 
'6'
PROCESSOR_REVISION 
'3a09'
PROGRAMDATA 
'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMFILES(X86) 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432 
'C:\\Program Files'
PSMODULEPATH 
('C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules')
PUBLIC 
'C:\\Users\\Public'
QUERY_STRING 
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD 
'GET'
RUN_MAIN 
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_NAME 
'vortex.data.microsoft.com'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME 
'Console'
SYSTEMDRIVE 
'C:'
SYSTEMROOT 
'C:\\WINDOWS'
TEMP 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TMP 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN 
'DESKTOP-GKBKG6I'
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE 
'DESKTOP-GKBKG6I'
USERNAME 
'Victor.INC'
USERPROFILE 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC'
WINDIR 
'C:\\WINDOWS'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper 
''
wsgi.input 
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x04995D90>
wsgi.multiprocess 
False
wsgi.multithread 
True
wsgi.run_once 
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version 
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module mysite.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES 
{}
ADMINS 
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS 
[]
APPEND_SLASH 
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS 
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR 
'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\Desktop\\mysite'
CACHES 
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS 
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS 
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN 
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME 
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE 
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW 
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME 
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS 
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS 
False
DATABASES 
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\Victor.INC\\Desktop\\mysite\\db.sqlite3',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS 
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS 
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS 
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS 
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG 
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS 
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR 
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER 
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE 
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL 
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE 
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE 
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS 
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND 
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST 
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT 
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE 
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE 
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX 
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT 
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL 
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS 
False
FILE_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS 
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR 
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK 
0
FIXTURE_DIRS 
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME 
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH 
None
FORM_RENDERER 
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS 
[]
INSTALLED_APPS 
['news',
 'mainApp',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
INTERNAL_IPS 
[]
LANGUAGES 
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI 
['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE 
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME 
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE 
False
LOCALE_PATHS 
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG 
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL 
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL 
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS 
[]
MEDIA_ROOT 
''
MEDIA_URL 
''
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE 
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES 
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT 
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS 
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF 
'mysite.urls'
SECRET_KEY 
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER 
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS 
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT 
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY 
None
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL 
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE 
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN 
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE 
False
SESSION_ENGINE 
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH 
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST 
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER 
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'mysite.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT 
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT 
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS 
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS 
[]
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL 
'/static/'
TEMPLATES 
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': [],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS 
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR 
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS 
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE 
'UTC'
USE_I18N 
True
USE_L10N 
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR 
False
USE_TZ 
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST 
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT 
False
WSGI_APPLICATION 
'mysite.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT 
'F Y'
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.
```

settings.py

```html
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sczyf1%0st32=q@i=2dubq27#wv2jnv*y$zm_md)*$p(n3!5k)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'news',
    'mainApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

news/urls.py

```html
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from news.models import Articles

app_name = 'news'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset = Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20], template_name="news/posts.html")),
]
```

news/models.py

```html
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
 post = models.TextField()
 date = models.DateTimeField()

 def __str__(self):
  return self.title
```

posts.html

```html
{% extends "mainApp/second_page_style.html" %}

 {% block content %}
  {% for post in object_list %}

  <a href="/news/{{post.id}}"><h3>{{post.title}}</h3></a>
  <h5>{{post.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h5>

  {% endfor }
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: put a templates folder inside your news folder, then put a subfolder called news in it, and your html files in that. /mysite/news/templates/news/posts.html

Comment: Thanks for your response